# RaphaelJs : How to add some text to an area defined by a path?

Tags: graphics, svg, raphael

I have an SVG image of the united states which I've drawn with a little bit of help from Raphaël js:

http://jsfiddle.net/zCRkg/2/

What I want to do is place some text to the right of each state when you hover over it. The problem is that, since each state is a path, its quite difficult to determine the x & y coordinates for where to place the label.

So, does anyone know a way of calculating the centre of a path using Raphaël? If failing that anyone know how to do this given a an array of vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [getBBox function in Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.getBBox). It will give you a bounding box object that you can use to calculate the central point of the path:

```
var bbox = st.getBBox();
var text = r.text(bbox.x + bbox.width/2, bbox.y + bbox.height/2, "Foo");
```

I [forked your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FpJT5/) and made it show a static text in the middle of each state on hover. Picking up the state name from your data is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

the average of the difference between each coord should give you the centre, but thats probably not the most efficient way